# disable all keyboard shortcuts in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, blocking

I want to disable all keyboard shortcuts in windows, not only the WIN-X ones, but also the CTRL-X ones.

I have found a way to disable the WIN-X ones, by using the registry editor and navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Exlporer` and adding a key `NoWinKeys` and setting it to `0`. However, I haven't yet found something like that for the CTRL-X shortcuts.

I want to do this without using any third party tools, preferably using Group Policy or the registry.

Comment: In what programs do you want to disable the ctrl+x? Do you mind that ctrl+fx is also disabled? You can follow the instructions on this page to completely disable the ctrl-key using the scancode for ctrl instead of win-key (but it will also disable ctrl+fx). http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For disabling any physical key on the keyboard is a registry entry too.

It's in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]`
You create a key with the name `Scancode Map`. It can redirect any key to another key or disable it.

That key is a hex-value with the following meaning:

```
00,00,00,00 Header: Version. Set to all zeroes.
00,00,00,00 Header: Flags. Set to all zeroes.
03,00,00,00 3 entries in the map (including null entry).
00,00,xx,yy key xx xx -> Disable (0x00) but can also be another key
00,00,xx,xx key yy yy -> Disable (0x00).
00,00,00,00 Null entry.
```

To completely disable the CTRL you only need two entries (plus null).
The Left <kbd>Left-CTRL</kbd> (1d 00) and <kbd>Right-CTRL</kbd> (1d e0).

So you can create a .reg file like this: `Disable_CTRL-key.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,1d,00,00,00,1d,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Execute (double click) the .reg file and log out and back in (or restart your computer). Now your CTRL-keys are completely disabled.

Other useful keys to know:

```
1d 00    Left Ctrl
1d e0    Right Ctrl
38 00    Left Alt
38 e0    Right Alt
5b e0    Left Windows Key
5c e0    Right Windows Key
5d e0    Windows Menu Key
```

If you are not comfortable with changing the registry or you want other keys too you can use the program [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to edit them more easily. It also has a convenient list of all keys so you can just add them in a window.

[image: SharpKeys]

Comment: This is the `REG_BINARY` value data to disable the Windows Flag key on the keyboard from the console..... `00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000` but I'll have to dig to see if it does anything further but perhaps this codeplex tool you use can shed some light on that. Something I noticed though, is it does not see to take effect within an RDP session on the machine so it seems to be console specific.